# how can I get this ruby Visual qr Code generator working properly

Tags: ruby, linux, terminal, rubygems

I'm trying to get this ****Visual QR** code generator** from this [GitHub](https://github.com/orzFly/VisualQR) repo working but I keep getting an error message, the repo is marked as read-only, and I cannot get any answer from the creator.

This is the error message I'm getting when generating a VISUAL QR code.

```
visualqr.rb: undefined method `dark?' for
#<RQRCode::QRCode:0x000055819b1d2e10>
```

I did research online but nothing useful came up.

I checked the ruby code and found the line with the related error
`data[y + 1][x + 1] = true if qr.dark?(x, y)`
If I remove that line I get an output but the QR barcode doesn't work.

Can somebody help me solve this?

Comment: Please reread the posting guidelines. There is not nearly enough detail to help solve your issue. You need to show all of the relevant code that YOU have written around that error, the stack trace, etc.

Comment: Also why are you using that repo and not something that is actually maintained like https://github.com/whomwah/rqrcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify a related version of rqrcode gem in Gemfile as follow:

```
# Gemfile

gem 'rqrcode', '~> 0.10'

...
```

Then run `bundle install`.

Add to the visualqr.rb file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'bundler/setup' # Add this line on top of `require` block
```

Run: `ruby visualqr.rb "data" bg.png  out.png`

The reason is the breaking change in `rqrcode` library somewhere between v0.x and v1.x.

Comment: Thanks that worked, I had a feeling things changed on the rqrcode library but since my knowledge of ruby is really limited I was trying a different approach. Once again thank you for your help.